# Google Sheets filter by todays date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, datefilter

I have created a google sheet of sporting events, this then filters to different websites using the ninjatables wordpress plugin.

Not all websites need to display all the games.

The 'Games' sheet contains a list of all the events throughout the year, I then have a query to filter the results into individual sheets for individual sites, displaying only certain sporting events for that site, such as;

Site 1 = Rugby and Football

Site 2 = Football and Basketball

Everything so far works fine.

I am now trying to add a date filter so that games before todays date are no longer visible.

```
=query(Games!A:Y, "where A > date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and (F = 'Football') or (F = 'Rugby')",1)
```

If I change the greater than (>) sign to less than(<), it filters out the results to only show the games before todays date just fine, but for some reason my current query does not filter out games before today.

I have tried changing the formating on my date column on the games sheet (mm/dd/yy, dd/mm/yyyy, yyy-mm-dd, etc) not sure that that has anything to do with it, but couldnt hurt to try.

If anyone could shed any light as to where I may be going wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use greater than or equal `>=` as an operator.

**EDIT:** Boolean operations are evaluated **left to right**, so `A > date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'` and `(F = 'Football')` are evaluated first, then this is or'd with `(F = 'Rugby')`.

This is fixed by grouping the column F conditions with parenthesis.

```
=query(Games!A:Y, "where A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and ((F = 'Football') or (F = 'Rugby'))",1)
```

This will display entries greater than or equal to today's date, and if column F is (Football or Rugby)

**Sample Query:**

[image]

Comment: I had tried adding the 'equals to' operator, but sadly to no avail. Weirdly enough if i add it to the less than it works, it will show todays game and anything before todays date.. I just cannot figure out as to why it wont work the way round I need and filter any dates previous to today.. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet so we can check with your exact dataset.

Comment: Think this is it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k_BbfIVyZzU58l7TdInmiC5mcxFjhPfuUukIPCIvzGg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for providing the copy. I edited my answer with the complete solution. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: No problem at all, thanks for taking the time to take a look. This seems to be working as expected now, I knew it was something simple, turns out just a couple of parenthesis were needed. Thank you!!

Comment: Very much appreciated :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!